# Query table by filtering criteria from rows

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Need help with querying in c# with entity framework.

I have an advanced search page where I can select multiple options from a checkbox list. These selected options should be filtered from a table which has each option as a value.

> This is the snapshot of my table.

[image]

> From this table, my select options are below:

[image]

If I select more than one of them, I need to retrieve the data which holds for all the values checked. i.e., I should apply an "AND" condition with the selected values to get the employee who has all the selected values. The below code wouldnt apply the filter as an "AND" operation because I am comparing each item individually with the list of rows.

```
foreach (var item in UIFilter.SecurityOptions)
                {
                    securityOverrideList.AddRange(
                        secureDbContext.
                        SecurityOverride.
                        Where(p => p.SECURITY_ROLE_CD.Equals(item)).
                        Select(p => p.EMPL_ID));
                }
```

Can someone suggest me a way to do this in C# as I am not having access to create procedures in my DB right now.

Comment: why you need a `foreach` loop here?

Answer (score 0):

Could you probably try the following:

```
var potentialEmployees = secureDbContext.SecurityOverride.Where(a => UIFilter.SecurityOptions.Contains(a.SECURITY_ROLE_CD));
var securityOverrideList = potentialEmployees.Select(x => x.EMPL_ID).Distinct();
foreach (var item in UIFilter.SecurityOptions)
{
    var subsetEmployeeIds = potentialEmployees.Where(a => a.SECURITY_ROLE_CD == item).Select(x => x.EMPL_ID);
    securityOverrideList = securityOverrideList.Where(a => subsetEmployeeIds.Contains(a));
}
```

Looking at your structure, there would be no single row that would meet all of the selected roles. As such, we need to get all potential employeeId (assuming this is what you are looking for as you are projecting only the employee id).

Next, we loop through again for each security role to ensure that the securityOverrideList becomes smaller as it needs to meet all of those criteria.